# how do you get strings from the xml on the toast

Tags: android, string, android-toast

how do i get my strings from the xml in on my toast

like

```
<string name="Pic_taken">Billedet er nu blevet taget! </string>
```

in on this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Billedet er nu blevet taget!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Pic_taken), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the Toast API:

> public static Toast makeText(Context context, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration)

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.Pic_taken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Format:

```
Toast.makeText(Context context, @StringRes int resId, @Duration int duration);
```

So, for your case the code will be:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.Pic_taken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```